# Calling an API in visual studio code using Python

Tags: python, json, api, visual-studio-code

I am trying to call the marvel API from here: https://developer.marvel.com

The code I wrote for it:

```
import requests, json
from pprint import pprint

# Call an API
url = "http(s)://gateway.marvel.com/"
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status() # check for errors

# Load JSON data into a Python variable.
jsonData = json.loads(response.text)
pprint(jsonData)
```

When I run it, I receive the error :
`requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 409 Client Error: Conflict for url:`

Comment: The URL is malformed. Use `url = "https://gateway.marvel.com/"` ;-)

Comment: The `(s)` likely means it is optional. use `http://` or `https://` not `http(s)`. Note though that the base urls is not likely going to return anything. You likely need to get a more specific endpoint. like `https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters` or something like that.

Comment: Notwithstanding the URL format issue and assuming you get a JSON response, you can call response.json() to get the payload. Having said that, I don't think the response from that URL is what you're hoping for

Answer (score 0):

It is from rest api

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint

# Call an API
response = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
response.raise_for_status()  # check for errors
print(response.status_code)
# Load JSON data into a Python variable.
jsonData = json.loads(response.text)
pprint(jsonData)
```

Comment: Do you realise that *print(response.status_code)* will **always** emit 200 with that code? Also, response.json() obviates the need for importing *json*

Comment: yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the url you posted is just a placeholder? The correct format should be something like https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?apikey=yourpublickey.

You also need the to specify an endpoint, in my example I used the /characters endpoint.

Try removing the response.raise_for_status(). It should continue and give you an error message with what is wrong (according to the docs, almost all errors will give you a status code of 409).

```
import requests, json
from pprint import pprint

# Call an API
url = "https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?apikey=yourpublickey."
response = requests.get(url)
# response.raise_for_status() # check for errors

# Load JSON data into a Python variable.
jsonData = json.loads(response.text)
pprint(jsonData)
```